# Lang-Trotter conjecture: known for any curves?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

There is not a single elliptic curve for which the Lang-Trotter conjecture is known, right? Just double-checking.

Answer (score 2):

Nicholas M. Katz writes in his article [Lang-Trotter revisited](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nmk/LTrevisit135new.pdf) the following, on page 12:
"*There are no cases whatever of a pair $(C;A)$ for which this conjecture
is known*. The conjectures are also formulated for other cases than elliptic curves, but I think Katz here says explicitly that also no elliptic curve is known to satisfy the statement of the (original) conjecture.